# Initialize plist with root element

Tags: iphone, plist

I am trying to create an RSS reader for iPhone, first thing i trying to do is create a plist to hold a bunch of NSDictionary. But when a create the plist in my appDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) the root elements is a NSDictionary, but i want a NSArray to hold the other elements.

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

the filePath variable is the path to the document folder. the code to create the plist is running ok.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a empty array (NSArray) and write that to file?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:

And in a similar fashion do

[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] (or a NSMutableArray if you prefer that)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfFile:

Answer (score 0):

Alloc an `NSMutableArray`, then use `[NSMutableArray addObject:dictionary` to add the dictionaries.

At what point in time you write the Array with the dictionaries to persistent storage (file) is your choice, but you don't need to write an empty file first. Just ensure you update the file before entering background and/or before exiting the App

Comment: I write the Array when i receive a  UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification in my view controller.

Comment: You might want to consider to trigger an additional write in applicationWillResignActive, because a user can put the app into background and kill it while in background. In that case and when you use only UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification the latest data will not be written.

Comment: ahh thanks! I am doing as you told me, i going to write the array when i receive those notifications.